# Completing an item adds two new lines to it, without such a thing in the function it self

Tags: javascript, list

I have recreated a todo list on my own, after I've watched a tutorial, and everything works fine, 99% of it at least. Theres only one tiny problem, nothing deal breaking, but it bothers me a lot because I can't find the origin of the issue in the function, even though I've narrowed it down using the debugger. The problem itself is that, whenever I mark an item as "completed" in my todo list, it adds two new empty lines to it (like if someone literally clicked Enter x2, that's how its showcased in the console log). And the issue happens "per item", so its not like if I mark one as completed, it adds two new lines to each item, but just to the one being marked / unmarked. Here's a chunk of the code with the function that I supposedly narrowed it down to:

```
function completeItem(){
    const item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    const parent = item.parentNode;
    const id = parent.id;
    const value = item.innerText;

    if(id === "todo"){
        data.todo.splice(data.todo.indexOf(value), 1)
        data.completed.push(value);

        // Notification.
        notification.innerHTML = "<p>Task completed.</p>";
        notification.classList.add("notification");
        notification.classList.add("notificationCompleted");
        setTimeout(() => {
            notification.classList.remove("notification");
            notification.classList.remove("notificationCompleted");
            notification.innerHTML = "";
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        data.completed.splice(data.completed.indexOf(value), 1);
        data.todo.push(value);
    }
    dataObjectUpdate();
    console.log(data);

    const target = (id === "todo") ? document.getElementById("completed"):document.getElementById("todo");

    parent.removeChild(item);
    target.insertBefore(item, target.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Also here's the link to the whole script file on hastebin, if needed:
https://hastebin.com/kuwomiqazu.cs .
Here's a link to a codepen showcasing the issue:
https://codepen.io/pecko95/pen/XBpoGr
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there some HTML that went along with this?

Comment: Not much, only the unordered lists in which these items will be stored in. 90% of it is dynamically created by user input.

Comment: of course, but you haven't given us that HTML, so we have to re-create it ourselves -- and that will delay us answering you

Comment: My bad, here's the HTML on hastebin: https://hastebin.com/oyetodakuv.xml

Comment: Don't post information essential to the question in a link, put it in your question itself

Comment: Noted, sorry for that, I'm relatively new to all this. Will update the post with a codepen as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> textContent returns the text content of all elements, while innerText
>   returns the content of all elements, except for `<script>` and `<style>`
>   elements.

If you use textContent bug will be fixed.

Comment: It did work ! Thanks a lot. By the way, in Mozzila Developer Edition, it worked just fine with innerText, it had that issue only in Chrome. But now with textContent, it works properly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
const value = item.innerText;
```

with

```
const value = item.textContent;
```